# Deleting a CoreData object, then calling [tableView reloadData] causes a SIGABRT

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data

I'm supporting deleting rows in a UIView that includes a tableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
  [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController
            objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
  NSError *error;
  if (![[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
   NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@, %@", error, [error userInfo],
                    [error localizedDescription]);
  }
  else {NSLog(@"Apparently successful");}
  [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
}
```

When I try this out, I get the "Apparently successful" message in the console, but then a SIGABRT in configureCell.  It's as though somewhere the object hasn't been deleted, and configureCell is trying to present a missing object.  (When I re-run the app, though, the record is  gone.)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Posting some more of your code would help us, especially your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, which probably is the culprit here.

Comment: Ok, here's what happens before crashing:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
[...boilerplate stuff that won't fit in this comment...]

 [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell
    atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
 NSManagedObject *mo = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 int objtype = [[(Type *)[mo valueForKey:@"type"] globalid] intValue];

Then -- BOOM!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have that `[self.tableView reloadData]` there when using a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

When you delete an object, the right `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method will be called for you, where you should take care of updating your table view.

Create an empty *Navigation-based Application* and check the *Use Core Data for Storage* checkbox. What you will get is an empty project that does all this correct. It will be a good example.

Comment: Hmm -- not sure about this.  I removed [self.tableView reloadData] and the table did not update (row didn't disappear).  When I closed the ViewController (a modal VC) and reopened it, I got the same SIGABRT.  This is a ViewController that contains a UITableView as a property, implements <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>.

Comment: Show more code then. And a SIGABRT also comes with a stack trace that will probably give a good hint.

Comment: If the table did not update then you are not implementing the delegate methods for the `NSFetchedResultsController` correctly.  @St3fan is correct in his answer.  Showing the full error would also be helpful.

Comment: I finally had a chance to look at this more carefully, and you're correct, I hadn't implemented NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate properly -- the Apple docs were helpful getting me there.